# Norm preservation properties of a unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, unitary-matrices

Tried to prove the following facts:

1. If $B \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ is unitary  (i.e. $ B^{-1} = B^{*}$), then:

   - $\forall x\in \mathbb{C}^n :\| Bx \|_2 = \| x \|_2  $
   - $\forall A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ :  $ \| BA \|_F = \| A \|_F  $ (where $ \| . \|_F $ denotes Frobenius norm).
2. $\forall A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}): \| AB \|_{ \infty} \leq \| A \|_{ \infty}\| B \|_{ \infty}   $

In (1),tried to conduct direct algebraic manipulations from the definitions of the norms, but I obtained no results. 
  In (2) the use of definition $ \| B \|_{ \infty} := max\{\frac{\|Bx\|}{\|x\|}: x\in \mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\} \}$ and the inequality $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|$ gives straightforward result. However, the use of definition $\|B\|\ _{\infty} :=max\{ \sum_{j=1}^{n}|b_{ij}|: i\in \{1,...n\}\}$ does not give direct results.

I would be thankful for hints/advices!

Comment: Hints: $\left|\left| v \right|\right|_2 = \sqrt{v^\ast v}$ and $\left|\left|A\right|\right|_F = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}\left(A^*A\right)}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is to operate with the squares of the norms, rather than with the norms themselves.  These squares are given by the appropriate scalar products, whose properties we will use.

Using the Hermitian product, $(x, y)$:
$$
|| Bx ||_{2}^{2} = (Bx, Bx) = (x, B^{*}Bx) = (x, x) = ||x||_{2}^{2}.
$$
For the Frobenius norm, using the corresponding inner product:
$$
||B A||_{F}^{2} = \mbox{tr }[(B\,A)^{*} B\,A] = \mbox{tr }[A^{*} B^{*} B \, A] = \mbox{tr }[A^{*} \, A] = ||A||_{F}^{2}
$$

Comment: Now I see. So obvious... By the way, thanks for help!

Comment: Sure.  Another useful exercise (and far from obvious) is this: in a normed vector space, the norm is given by a scalar product if and only if the norm obeys the parallelogram law.  BTW, I consider Halmos's *Linear Algebra Problem Book* a great source.

Comment: Have this problem book(it is great). Thanks for additional problem!

Comment: What rule allows us to multiply the matrix into the inner product? I know we can do this with scalars, but I hadn't seen it with matrices.

Comment: @HappyFace, the matrix is not "multiplied into the inner product".  The matrix B acts on a vector x, which produces another vector, y=Bx.  Next, we take the good old inner product of the vector y with itself: (y,y) = ( Bx, Bx ).

Unless I am misunderstanding what you are asking?

Comment: I do not understand how this part follows: `(,)=(,∗ )`. I know `(b,b)=(,b* b)` for scalar b (part of the definition IIRC), but B here is a matrix.

Comment: @HappyFace. B is a linear transformation, and B* is the *dual transformation* of B--I think your difficulty is just not being familiar with that concept.  The asterisk denotes, not the complex conjugate, but the dual transformation.  In the special case when B = bI, where b is a complex scalar, then it reduces to (x, b* bx), where b* turns out to be the complex conjugate of b.

See [Halmos's book](https://archive.org/details/HalmosP.R.FiniteDimensionalVectorSpaces.SpringerVerlag205s/mode/2up)

Answer (score 3):

$$
||Bx||_2 = \sum_i\left(\sum_j B_{ij}x_j) \right)^* \left(\sum_k B_{ik}x_k) \right) $$
$$
\\
\left(\sum_j B_{ij}x_j) \right)^* = \sum_j B_{ij}^*x_j^*  =  \sum_j (B^T_{ji})^*x_j^* =  \sum_j B^{-1}_{ji}x_j^* 
$$
$$
||Bx||_2 = \sum_i\left(\sum_j B^{-1}_{ji}x_j^*  \right)^* \left(\sum_k B_{ik}x_k) \right) \\
= \sum_j\sum_k \left(  \sum_iB^{-1}_{ji}  B_{ik}  \right) x_j^*x_k
=\sum_j\sum_k \delta_{jk} x_j^*x_k = \sum_j  x_j^*x_k = ||x||_2
$$

The equality for the Frobenius norm follows directly since for any arbitrary $x$ the sum of the quares for each column of $BAx$ matches the sum of the squares for that same column of $Ax$.